# function with multiple where

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, conditional-statements, where-clause

I need to have a function with more then one WHERE condition from other table:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[Table2](@Id INT) 
RETURNS money
AS 
BEGIN
 DECLARE @cost money
 SELECT @koszt = SUM(Value)
 FROM [dbo].[Cost]
  WHERE ([ID_CostCategory] --I need to add here one more condition [ID_Department]
  return @cost
END
```

Please help how to obtain it.

Comment: Why can't you combine multiple conditions with `AND`?

Comment: @marc_s I am using SQL Server 2008 r2.

Comment: @PoByBolek, i get an error: "An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near 'and'."

Comment: Your WHERE clause should look something like this: `WHERE ([ID_CostCategory] = 3 AND [ID_Department] = 5)`. Is this the case?

Comment: I have a Cost table with ID_CostCategory, ID_Department, Value column. Those are not unique. Using function above I can get the sum of all records from Value column based on ID_CostCategory. But I would like to have the sum of records from Value table based on ID_CostCategory and ID_Department.

Comment: So I need that for each department I have different cost categories assigned. And the function above would help me to see it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, I would use an inline UDF instead of scalar function for performance reasons.

Second, there are two options:

1) A function that shows total for every department

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[Table2](@pID_CostCategory INT) 
RETURNS TABLE
AS 
RETURN
    SELECT  [ID_Department], SUM(Value) AS koszt
    FROM    [dbo].[Cost]
    WHERE   [ID_CostCategory] = @pID_CostCategory
    GROUP BY[ID_Department];
GO
```

or

2) A function which has two parameters, the second parameter being optional

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[Table2](@pID_CostCategory INT, @pID_Department INT=NULL) 
RETURNS TABLE
AS 
RETURN
    SELECT  SUM(Value) AS koszt
    FROM    [dbo].[Cost]
    WHERE   [ID_CostCategory] = @pID_CostCategory
    AND     ([ID_Department] = @pID_Department OR @pID_Department IS NULL)
GO
```

Comment: I am doing smth wrong. From the beggining. I have Cost table with:ID_Cost, Value, Name, ID_CostCategory,ID_Department. Right now I need to create a separate table (CategoryDepartment) which will include ID_CategoryDepartment, ID_Department, ID_CostCategory and the last column which will present SUM of values from Cost table (per each ID_Department or each ID_CostCategory). Cost categories can be assigned to different Departments, so Department 1 can have CostCategory 1 (sum from values from Cost table is 500) and Cost Category 2 (sum from values from Cost table is 200), and so on to all Depart

Comment: Create another question.

Answer (score 0):

If I unterstood your comments correctly, maybe introducing a second paramter to your function will do the trick:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[Table2](@CategoryId INT, @DepartmentId INT) 
   RETURNS money
AS 
BEGIN
   DECLARE @cost money
   SELECT @cost = SUM(Value)
   FROM [dbo].[Cost]
   WHERE ([ID_CostCategory] = @CategoyId AND [ID_Department] = @DepartmentId)
   return @cost
END
```